# Package C console application (Visual Studio '13)

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, console-application

I wrote a basic program for my mom, and now I want her to be able to use it. Obviously, it works on my computer. Getting the `.exe` file from the project folder, and putting it on her computer doesn't work: it says `MSVCR120d.dll is missing` whenever the `.exe` is run. Makes sense--as her computer doesn't have Visual Studio on it. However, I tried installing the *Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013*, and that didn't work either.

To be honest, I'm not looking to spending hours of time to piece this all together. This is something I will more than likely never do again--I've already done some searching and can only find subjects speaking of C++ distributions. I want a way to get the console app on her computer to work.

Comment: The redistributable only installs the required release libraries, but you're trying to run a debug executable.  That's what the `d` at the end of the library name means.  You could try compiling as release, or if you need to stick to debug statically link as described below.  Static linking has its own issues, but for something simple you're probably fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more easy way is **link statically**. That mean embed all the needed code to the app to run, in the final binary (.exe), eliminating dependency of other libraries.

- Go to **Project Properties**
- Go to **Configuration Properties**
- Go to **C/C++**
- Go to **Code Generation**
- Change **Runtime Library** (in Debug to **Multi-Threaded Debug /MTd** and in Release to **Multi-Threaded /MT**)